# Could not download full-sdk-4.0.1.aar (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.0.1)

Tags: build.gradle, agora.io, agora-implementation

I am try to use agora sdk with all credentials but after build run getting error.

> Blockquote[image]

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactResolveException: Could not download full-sdk-4.0.1.aar (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.0.1)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactResolveException: Could not download full-sdk-4.0.1.aar (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.0.1): No cached version available for offline mode
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Failed to transform full-sdk-4.0.1.aar (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-res, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

I completed as per doc : https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/get-started/get-started-sdk

Answer (score 0):

```
Got the solution:  i removed unreachable maven urls from settings.gradle
        maven { url "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter" }
        maven { url "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public" }

& downgrade not found dependencies and fixed for me.
```